# Struts 2- how to fetch hidden valueof a td in action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have some hidden values of tr. How do i pass it to action in struts 2. On click of vendor name i want the hidden values to be available in action.

My jsp code is :

```
 <s:iterator value="vendorDetailsListFE" var = "vendorDetail"  status="incr"> 

<tr class= "ListRow0">




<td class="ListItem"><a href="addVendor.action?&action=update"><s:property value="#vendorDetail.vendorName" /></a> </td>
<td class="ListItem"><s:property value="#vendorDetail.vendorTypeDesc" /> </td>
<td><s:hidden name="hiddenVendorId" value="#vendorDetail.vendorId"></s:hidden>
</td>
 </tr>
```

My java code is :

```
public class VendorAction extends BaseAction {


    private String hiddenVendorId;





    public void setHiddenVendorId(String hiddenVendorId) {
        this.hiddenVendorId = hiddenVendorId;
    }


    public String createOrUpdateVendor(){
        LOGGER.info("entering createOrUpdateVendor method");
        String actionReturn;
        LOGGER.info("entering createOrUpdateVendor");
        String action = getServletRequest().getParameter("action");

        LOGGER.info("action"+action);
        vendorTypeDetailsDomainList = adminManager.findAllVendorType();
        LOGGER.info(vendorTypeDetailsDomainList.length + "vendorTypeDetailsDomainList.size");

        for(VendorDetails vendorDetailsBean : vendorTypeDetailsDomainList){    
            Vendor vendorType = new Vendor();
            vendorType.setVendorTypeId(vendorDetailsBean.getVendorTypeId());
            vendorType.setVendorTypeDesc(vendorDetailsBean.getVendorTypeDesc());
            vendorTypeDetailsListFE.add(vendorType);
        }
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("create")){
            vendor = new Vendor();
            vendor.setActiveFlag("true");
            //actionReturn = "createVendor"
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("action"+action);
            vendor = new Vendor();

            LOGGER.info(getHiddenVendorId()+"VENDOR ID");



        }
         return "success";
    }   
}
```

I am getting hidden value as null. Kindly advise how to fetch hidden value of td in java.

Comment: if hidden value is null the you should get it as string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Struts? If so, i can give you an example how it works for me.

```
class YourPersonalBean {

     private String hiddenProperty;

     public void setHiddenProperty(String hiddenProperty) {
           ...
     }

     public String getHiddenProperty() {
           ...
     }
}
```

**form.jsp**

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html">
     ...
    <jsp:useBean id="personalForm" class="ru.cus.view.action.beans.YourPersonalBean" scope="session">

    <html:form action="/personalAction">
        <html:hidden property="hiddenProperty">
    </html:form>
```

**config.xml**

```
<action-mappings>
    <action path="/personalAction" 
            name="personalForm" 
            type="ru.cus.view.action.beans.YourPersonalBean" 
            parameter="action" scope="session">
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your href attribute and send the attribute via GET.

```
<a href="addVendor.action?&action=update&hiddenVendorId=<s:property value="#vendorDetail.vendorId" />"></a>
```